# Problems with run from USB installation creation and lack of option to run from USB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, usb-creator

I wanted to use and try Ubuntu from a USB flash drive so I used the Universal USB installer from PenDriveLinux. I selected `ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso` since I have a 64bit processor on an HP 2760p. I saw no other 64bit choices.

When I booted from the USB drive, the only alternatives pertaining to running the OS were "Install" and "Rescue ...".  There was no alternative to "Try" the OS from the USB drive.  I was afraid to choose install for fear it would ruin my Windows installation.  What should I do?

Prior to this there were other problems.  If I downloaded an ISO version of Linux and tried to select it from its download directory, the USB installer would not display any "ISO" versions in that directory  even though the OPEN window indicated it was filtering for those files.

As much as I loved an installation of Linux I got to play with some years back, I'm ready to give up and stick to Windows despite all of its problems.  It makes the basics, like installation, easy for anyone.  Can't install it, can't use it.  I'm an engineer and I can't get Linux or the USB Universal Installer to work as directed.

I'd love to dual-boot Windows and Linux however I understand the boot loader can get corrupted and needs to be reinstalled.  That would not be a problem if it can be easily done from a CD or especially from a small, handy USB stick.  Well if I can't trust the most trusted Pen Drive installer to work properly ie. can't filter or display files properly, how can I trust a boot-loader repair program.  I'd really love to use Linux.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

At first I suggest preparing your USB with the [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). I've done this last week and have had your missing *try*-option after booting from USB. The process of preparing your USB-drive properly is seperated into easy and comprehensive steps. All you need is an ubuntu image (e.g. the one have downloaded already) and an USB-drive.

Also the bootloader (i.e. grub 2 for ubuntu 12.04) operates very well IMO. It should detect your Windows installation automatically and add it to boot menu. Just get yourself familiar with some manuals and tutorials and you'll soon get enough confidence to press the all-mighty *Install*-button ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use yumi instead of universal USB installer it is better than it you can download it from [HERE](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
2. If you want to have a dual boot of Ubuntu distributions with windows without the fear of getting boot loader corrupted you can use wubi.exe which installs it like other windows programs and you can easily uninstall ubuntu like other windows programmes.

You can find a complete tutorial about it [HERE](http://a2zpctricks.blogspot.com/2012/09/ubuntu-dual-boot-with-windows.html)